# null exception while setting value to datagrid cell in wpf.

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I had created a datagrid with three datagridtextcolumn and I hide the one datagrid text column. While I try to set the value to the hidden  datagrid text column I got the null exception. How can I resolve this. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance.

I use the following code to set the value in hidden datagrid text column.

```
void setValue()
{
     var tempdata = DatagridUtilities.GetCell(dgempShift,0,2);
    (tempdata.Content as TextBlock).Text = "data";
}
```

code for datagridutilities is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;


    public static class DatagridUtilities
    {
        private static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
        {
            T child = default(T);
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
                }
                if (child != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return child;
        }

        public static DataGridRow GetSelectedRow(this DataGrid grid)
        {
            return (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem);
        }
        public static DataGridRow GetRow(this DataGrid grid, int index)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
            if (row == null)
            {
                // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
                grid.UpdateLayout();
                grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
                row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
            }
            return row;
        }
        public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
        {
            if (row != null)
            {
                DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

                if (presenter == null)
                {
                    grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
                    presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
                }

                DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
                return cell;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, int row, int column)
        {
            DataGridRow rowContainer = grid.GetRow(row);
            return grid.GetCell(rowContainer, column);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you check what is the type for tempdata.Content?

Comment: Obviously, your content isn't TextBlock. Put a breakpoint and hover your mouse over "Content" to see what's the valid type...

Comment: put a break point in and see where the null value is

Comment: @AMR i put break point and null is in tempdata

Comment: If you set the `Visibility` of the `DataGridTextColumn` to `Collapsed`, it will be totally removed from the visual tree... in this case, try setting it to `Hidden` instead. If not, then please show us the code inside your `DatagridUtilities.GetCell` method.

Comment: @Sheridan i set visibility to Collapsed. still i got the same error

Comment: That's the opposite of what I suggested. Either way, please show us the code inside your `DatagridUtilities.GetCell` method.

Answer (score 0):

You said above that tempdata is null. This means 1 of a couple things.

A: You are calling `setValue()` automatically before your values are initialized.

This can be fixed by doing a null check within your method

```
void setValue()
{
    if(DatagridUtilities != null && DatagridUtilities.GetCell(dgempShift,0,2) != null){
        var tempdata = DatagridUtilities.GetCell(dgempShift,0,2);
        (tempdata.Content as TextBlock).Text = "data";
     }

}
```

B: You are calling `GetCell` and it is returning `null`. This can be fixed with the above null check but I would look more into WHY it is returning `null`.

You can verify that this is what is happening by setting a breakpoint before your exception happens, then, when your breakpoint is hit, highlight `DatagridUtilities.GetCell(dgempShift,0,2);`

Right click it and click `"Quick Watch"` this will allow you to see what that call is returning 
(This is also a good enviorment for quickly resolving issues like this)

C: The final likely problem is that `(tempdata.Content as TextBlock)` is returning null which is entirly possible because the `"as"` keyword allows for a nullable return.